# Database schema and table classes are not getting generated using sqldelight for Multiplatform project

Tags: android, kotlin-multiplatform, sqldelight

I have been trying to learn Kotlin multiplatform using the tutorial video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1w-LTUm_iDE from Phillip where he is explaining creating a Note app using Sqldelight. I have been doing exactly the same but i am getting weird issues where my Database class and entity classes are not getting generated and getting below errors.
[image]

Below is the shared folder build.gradle code : https://pastebin.com/RRc8atD4

and this is project level build.gradle :

```
plugins {
    //trick: for the same plugin versions in all sub-modules
    id("com.android.application").version("7.4.0").apply(false)
    id("com.android.library").version("7.4.0").apply(false)
    kotlin("android").version("1.8.10").apply(false)
    kotlin("multiplatform").version("1.8.10").apply(false)
    id("com.squareup.sqldelight").version("1.5.4").apply(false)
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete::class) {
    delete(rootProject.buildDir)
}
```

can anyone please let me know what is the exact issue with this code.